# SQL Server: How to recreate a computed column *only once*

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to change the computation logic for an existing computed column in SQL Server.

**And I want to keep the column name unchanged.**

I wrote a script to do this job. And the script would

1. Drop the computed column
2. Recreate the computed column with new computation logic with same name.

The issue is this script may run multiple times in the future, however I don't want this script to drop and create the column every time.

Is there some way to avoid this column to be deleted and created more than once?

One way I could think of is to create a dummy check constraint. 
So before drop and recreate the computed column, first check if that dummy check constraint exists or not.

If it does not exists, then create the dummy constraint and drop/create the computed column.

Not sure if there is any other easy way to solve this.

Comment: Why you need to do this? - I think you can have two columns then create two views from your table then use each of those views(that has a same name column from different columns) in your cases ;).

Comment: I think the computed column is irrelevant here. This question seems to boil down to "how do I avoid performing maintenance activities more than once?" which is a fairly broad topic.

Comment: For normal columns, that is quite easy I could update the column data directly without drop and recreate. However, it is different to computed column.

Answer (score 0):

you may rely upon the `computed_columns` system table:

```
SELECT  t.name
        ,SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS [schema_name]
        ,c.name
        ,c.definition
FROM    sys.computed_columns c
        JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id;
```

I think it will require some trial and error to get the correct code but you should be able to build a check script to verify the current formula and trigger the `DROP`/`CREATE` only when needed.

possible issue: if an outdated version of the script is run it may revert the formula to a previous version so a timestamp check must be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using hardcoded value (not good), this script might help.
You will have to use a hard coded column_id or better figure out a way to retrieve it (count columns for this table maybe?).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1(ID int identity(0, 1), V1 int NULL, V2 int NULL, V3  AS V1*V2)  ON [PRIMARY]

select top 10 * from sys.computed_columns where OBJECT_ID('table_1') = object_id 

If Exists(Select 1 From sys.computed_columns where OBJECT_ID('table_1') = object_id and name = 'v3' and column_id<=
4)
Begin
    Print 'Update Computed Column'
    Alter TAble Table_1 Drop column V3;
    Alter Table Table_1 Add V3 as V1*V2
End
Else
Begin
    Print 'No Update'
End

select top 10 * from sys.computed_columns where OBJECT_ID('table_1') = object_id
```